# When should I use/not use '-w' for fastboot flashing?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, factory-image

When should I use/not use '-w' for fastboot flashing?

Say I were to be manually flashing each img in the zip of a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).

Why one way or another? Do certain .img's need to be erased first?

I recently had a misflash where my internal storage was reduced from 64gb to 32gb and I am wondering if it could have been avoided. I resolved my particular problem by using `Format Data` in TWRP.

Answer (score 1):

You should wipe the data once, when you start.  This may not be necessary if you are (for example) only flashing a recovery, flashing a very similar ROM, etc.

You shouldn't need to erase images/partitions before flashing over them.